# Select field alias condition and multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have a hard time figuring out how to write my query to select data I need.

So the problem is that: I have one table and three other tables with foreign keys. I need to select all fields from 1st table and one from other three tables as alias based on which field is not null. In most cases two of three tables will have null values for specified column but if there are two non null values I want to pick first found.

Maybe I'm not explaining it good but I'll try with examle. Let's say I have this main table

```
Table_1
TableOneID int(11),
SomeOtherData text

Table_2
TableTwoID int(11),
TableOneID int(11),
TableTwoValue varchar(250)

Table_3
TableThreeID int(11),
TableOneID int(11),
TableThreeValue varchar(250)

Table_4
TableFourID int(11),
TableOneID int(11),
TableFourValue varchar(250)
```

So I want to do something like

```
SELECT *, (HERE TO SELECT FIRST NON NULL VALUE FROM Table_2(TableTwoValue), 
Table_3(TableThreeValue) or Table_4(TableFourValue)) AS ExtraField FROM Table_1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 USING(TableOneID) ..... LEFT JOIN Table_4 USING(TableOneID);
```

Is this possible to happen? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

I have to use COALESCE

```
SELECT COALESCE(TableTwoValue, TableThreeValue, TableFourValue) 
AS ExtraField FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change the database structure :

```
Table_1
TableOneID int(11),
SomeOtherData text

Table_X
ID int(11),
TableOneID int(11),
TableTwoValue varchar(250),
number int(11)
```

And in number you put the table number (1,2,3, etc.)
And then the query become much more easier.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question. I simplified the tables structure and I can't change them. In fact these tables hold more values and have different purpose. I just need to get first non null value for every row from this three tables..

Comment: Well, you can't select from a list of table like this : `SELECT FROM TABLE1 OR TABLE2`. But you can get the data from all the tables, and then look the needed information with the php, i don't think this is possible with only an sql query.